# I cannot seem to get the property to console.log in my react function

Tags: reactjs

My console allows me to receive array data and shows me it received an object but I can't access the object's properties. I need the information so I can route this information and create a movie div. I'm very new and fresh to React so can someone please explain to me how would I be able to make this possible, please.... When I console.log(movieID) it renders twice but the first time it's an undefined variable.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const Movie = (props) => {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const snatchMovies = () => {
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    // change ^^^ that line and grab the id from the URL
    // You will NEED to add a dependency array to this effect hook

       axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/movies/`)
        .then(response => {
          setMovie(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
snatchMovies()
  },[]);



  // Uncomment this only when you have moved on to the stretch goals
  // const saveMovie = () => {
  //   const addToSavedList = props.addToSavedList;
  //   addToSavedList(movie)
  // }

  if (!movie) {
    return <div>Loading movie information...</div>;
  }

  //const { title, director, metascore, stars } = movie;
  const movieId = movie.find(i => props.match.params.id === `${i.id}`);
  console.log(movieId.title)
  return "hi"
  /*

  return (
    <div className="save-wrapper">
      <div className="movie-card">
        <h2>{movieId.title}</h2>
        <div className="movie-director">
          Director: <em>{movieId.director}</em>
        </div>
        <div className="movie-metascore">
          Metascore: <strong>{movieId.metascore}</strong>
        </div>
        <h3>Actors</h3>

        {movieId.stars.map(star => (
          <div key={star} className="movie-star">
            {star}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="save-button">Save</div>
    </div>
  );
  */
}

export default Movie;
```

Comment: What you are getting for `console.log(movieId)`?

Comment: {id: 2, title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", director: "Peter Jackson", metascore: 92, stars: Array(3)}

Comment: So what is the issue? Are you getting any error?

Comment: So i see everytime i call movieId i receive an undefined object first and then it returns my object

Comment: The issue is i receive an error on movieID.title even though movieID is an object

Comment: Can you do a `JSON.stringify(movieId).title `and then inform me about the result

Comment: *"i receive an undefined object first"* – that is expected before the Ajax call finishes. Change the first `if` to `if (!movie || movie.length === 0) {`

Comment: Do proper formatting by removing the unnecessary commented code and attach the code where you are calling Movies. And the render is happening twice because of the improper calling of Movies and async axios request.

Answer (score 1):

I have put comments in the code with possible solutions, hope it helps you out. Just comment if you have any questions.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

//you can't export default props=>jsx because the linter
//  may complain about anonymous/unnamed function
//  but you can export default like this:
export default function Movie(props) {
  //renamed to movies because you are getting multiple movies
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  //made this simpler and removed id, you never use it
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/movies/`)
      .then(response => {
        setMovies(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  //you don't need to get movies again when id changes
  //  because you already have all the movies
  }, []);

  //changed movieId to movie since that is what you
  //  want to get 
  const movie = movies.find(
    i => props.match.params.id === `${i.id}`
  );

  //now it makes sence to check if movie (single) is falsy
  // before movie was [] and if([]) is always truthy
  if (!movie) {
    return <div>Loading movie information...</div>;
  }

  console.log(movie.title);
  return 'hi';
}
```

It would probably be better to have the effect fetch the particular movie by id, if you have millions of movies you don't want to get all of them and then filter out the one you need.

You are combining [presentational and container components](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components), this will be confusing later if you have lots of components. Better to rename Movie to MovieContainer and have that only use hooks then return Movie which will create the jsx. The container should not have to import React because it should not produce jsx by itself and instead just call the presentational component.

Example of a container [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/homebrew-redux/blob/master/example/src/Counter/Container.js) and the presentational component [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/homebrew-redux/blob/master/example/src/Counter/Counter.js)